# Can I show snackbar in a widget which directly has no scaffold but has in a parent widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, snackbar, scaffold

I want to use snack bar in a widget but the scaffold is in a different widget. I have used ScaffoldMessenger but not showing and no errors.[ScaffoldMessenger used in a widget that is two widget inside of parent widget which has a scaffold]

Answer (score 1):

If you pass the `BuildContext` (of the different widget which holds the `Scaffold`) into the widget from where you'd like to show the `Snackbar`, you should be able to use `ScaffoldMessenger.of(passedContext).showSnackBar()`

If this doesn't answer your question. Please provide a minimal code snippet of what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

also, you can show SnackBar using [GET](https://pub.dev/packages/get),

you have to add get in your pubspec.yml in dependencies section

code : Get.snackbar("Hi..", "How are you !");